# opencart SMTP newsletter error

Tags: smtp, opencart, newsletter

I'm getting an error when I try to send a newsletter to my clients in opencart. 
The problem is that when I send to one client it will send successfully. However, when I try to send to all of my clients, I get this error:

> EHLO not accepted from server.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Opencart will provide many newsletter  extension which is paid or free.

Refer this Links:

- [Newsletter](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=10651)--commerical
- [Newsletter1](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=10622)--commerical
- [Free newsletter](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_license=0&filter_search=newsletter)--free

Once that is included, it should be working fine.